# Performance on entityManager.refresh()

Tags: java, jboss, seam, entitymanager

I'm having an issue with entityManager refresh for a single entity taking a very long time, upwards of a minute.  I have a screen on which the user can edit a simple record, for example change someone's first name.  They can either save or cancel when they are done.  On the cancel action, I am performing the following line so that if they made changes, but did not want to save, it would clear the changes from the cached copy of the object.

`getEntityManager().refresh(getInstance());`

This is on an entityHome bean.  What I have ended up doing is used

`getEntityManager().clear();`

which accomplishes the same thing for me but runs in less than a second.

I am using EE5, JDBC to connect to the Oracle 11g DB, and JTA for transactions.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is taking so long?

Comment: Which JPA provider are you using? Perhaps enabling SQL logging will help you understand what's happening "behing" the refresh?

Answer (score 0):

`refresh()` reloads the entity from the database (it performs a `SELECT` and reloads the entity). This is always slower than `clear()` which only clears the first-level cache. Note however that if you `clear()` the cache and had other entities in it, you will have to `merge()` them (which implies a reload from DB as well).

One minute seems like a long time for a simple record to reload so I presume there are other factors at work here, such as locking.

Anyway, this happens because your "Cancel" button submits the form. Once the form is submitted, values are copied into the entity instance and it is marked dirty. The easiest way of avoiding this behavior is simply to not submit the form when pressing "Cancel": do a GET instead of POST using `<s:button/>` or `<s:link/>` for the "Cancel" button. This works except if you are submitting changes via AJAX, in this case the entity is already updated and set as dirty.